# Getting line number from an element with VTD

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, line-numbers, vtd-xml

I decided to use the VTD-Xml to parse a very big file. It worked great, but during parsing, there can be validation checks, which must be logged with the position of the validated field (line and column). I cannot find any way to get at least the line number of an element using VTD. And I don´t have any access to the source code of VTD in order to check the implementation with the VTDGen.

Could someone please help me, either with an example code, or at least with an explanation how could I get the line number? I can access to the VTDNav and the Autopilot at any time during the parsing process.

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little procedure within VTDGen that does the line number reporting... hope that could aid your effort of finding line #. Notice that os is the offset within a document.

```
private String formatLineNumber(int os) {
    int so = docOffset;
    int lineNumber = 0;
    int lineOffset = 0;

    if (encoding < FORMAT_UTF_16BE) {
        while (so <= os-1) {
            if (XMLDoc[so] == '\n') {
                lineNumber++;
                lineOffset = so;
            }
            //lineOffset++;
            so++;
        }
        lineOffset = os - lineOffset;
    } else if (encoding == FORMAT_UTF_16BE) {
        while (so <= os-2) {
            if (XMLDoc[so + 1] == '\n' && XMLDoc[so] == 0) {
                lineNumber++;
                lineOffset = so;
            }
            so += 2;
        }
        lineOffset = (os - lineOffset) >> 1;
    } else {
        while (so <= os-2) {
            if (XMLDoc[so] == '\n' && XMLDoc[so + 1] == 0) {
                lineNumber++;
                lineOffset = so;
            }
            so += 2;
        }
        lineOffset = (os - lineOffset) >> 1;
    }
    return "\nLine Number: " + (lineNumber+1) + " Offset: " + (lineOffset-1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast answer. I will check the code today and in case it works I will comment it also here.

Comment: I am trying to adapt the code into my code. I think it should work, but first I have to resolve the next 3 points:

Comment: 1.- encoding is probably the result of vn.getEncoding(), right?
2.- is the XMLDoc a class part of VTD? I treid to look for that class in the internet, but I couldn´t find it. 
3.- from the line 2 "int so = docOffset" -> which value may I assign to docOffset? or is the same as the passed parameter "int os"?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi again. Sorry for the delay. I am implementing the 3 points, you answered. ButI still have problems with the XMLDoc. I cannot find that class. Also in the jar file, the class is not present. Do you know maybe, what is the problem? I am importing the wrong JAR file? or can I replace the XMLDoc wih something else? For the topic 2, I change the docOffset in line 2 into: int so = vn.getTokenOffset(os);. Thank you very much for your answer in advance.